# Javascript design pattern for manipulating DOM API

Tags: javascript, dom, design-patterns

I read alot of topics, went through alot of JS plugins on github, and alot of them have their own way of structuring code and which pattern to use. In some cases there is obvious why he went that way. But when dealing with smaller stuff, not big SAP, which pattern have most "pros" to go with?

For now, i am going this way:
https://github.com/goranefbl/GENS-Javascript-Boilerplate/blob/master/main.js

Yes, it works just fine, but i am wondering for smaller plugins, especially the ones that are just manipulating DOM (creating new elements/moving around/adding events listeners etc...), what would be best pattern to go with and of course why? Maybe I dont need to pollute namespace for small stuff.

Here is the example of latest component: [gist.github.com/goranefbl/1b6144ee8cd8708c7511a1a2fb7c53a6](http://gist.github.com/goranefbl/1b6144ee8cd8708c7511a1a2fb7c53a6) 
Its just creating unordered lists below select field, for easy styling.

Going with example boilerplate from above just doesnt feel right, ie it feels to much for something like this.

Comment: As with all patterns, there is no one size fits all. It depends on what your goals are, etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree, like i mentioned at the start. Maybe i didnt explain it fully, here is the example of latest component: https://gist.github.com/goranefbl/1b6144ee8cd8708c7511a1a2fb7c53a6 its just creating unordered lists below select field that is allowing easy styling. Going with example boilerplate from above just doesnt feel right, ie it feels to much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a smaller pattern than the one you posted. Let's see what parts we can get rid of:

The `defaults` object and `extendDefaults` method aren't necessary, you can use

```
window.GENSPlugin = function(firstoption, secondoption) {
```

The question is, do you really need a plugin? You said you don't want to pollute the global namespace, so what about this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    // not accessible from outside the function
    var obj1 = document.getElementById("...");

    // accesible from outside
    window.obj2 = function() {
        ...
    }

})();
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i agree. The question might even be when to use patterns and when not to, for something pretty small like this, i might go your way with just closures.